# How to " order by id " JSON with Rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, rabl

I want json output order by id(child id)

Can I solve this problem ?

this is some code in my project

show.json.rabl (I used Rabl)

```
object @book
attributes :id , :name 

child :questions do
  attributes :id , :name
end
```

books_controller.rb

```
def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```

Sorry for my English , Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your app and what you want to accomplish, but you could define a `default_scope` in the `Question` model like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('id ASC')
end
```

Or you could define a `default_scope` in the `Book` model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope joins(:questions).order('questions.id ASC')
end
```

If you want eager load the `questions`, then use `includes` instead of `join`.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know RABL, but i think that you can just pass in a collection instead of a symbol. given, that you `:question` is a `has_many` relation on your `Book` class, you could just use a finder for that:

```
child @book.questions.order('id ASC') do
  attributes :id , :name
end
```

Comment: Yes , :question is a has_many relation on my Book class ,
Thank you, I try it but still don't work.

Comment: what do you mean by that? what is the resulting json?

Comment: btw, don't apologize or write thank you stuff to your questions.

Comment: this is my sample result : http://njtutor.heroku.com/books/1.json

, json don't sort by question id (result sort is : 56,57,58 ... 1,2,..  )

Comment: i don't think that RABL is re-ordering your result... what does `@book.questions.order('id ASC').map(&:id)` give you as a result?

Answer (score 0):

Do the ordering in the models and use Rabl to query the ordering method

Question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  scope :by_id, order('id ASC')
  # ...
end
```

and then have a method in Book

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :questions
  # ...
  def ordered_questions
    questions.by_id
  end
  # ...
end
```

Finally, your Rabl would be

```
object @book
child :ordered_questions do
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/387